# rails to_json.html_safe Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, html-safe

I have in my stock rails 3.1 app's projects#index.html.erb a javascript section to reads like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var projects = <%= @projects.to_json.html_safe -%>
  $(function () {
    // some other code...
  });
</script>
```

However, Chrome's console complains that "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

now, if I remove anything that follows the "var projects" line like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var projects = <%= @projects.to_json.html_safe -%>
</script>
```

everything is fine and when one typed "projects" in the Chrome javascript console, I do get the list of objects
    [ object, object, object, ..., object ]

I cannot work out what the issue is here, can you help?

Thanks!

Comment: try adding a `;` semicolon at the end of statement

Comment: I swear, I did try that, and that time didn't work. And now it works :) Well, that's life.. Thanks!! Oh, how do i choose you as the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding a `;` semicolon at the end of statement